# Sass Selector: When a tag is not in another tag

Tags: css, sass

I'm attempting to style different `code` blocks depending on which tag they are present in:

- `code` blocks that are inside a `pre` tag, and
- `code` blocks that are **NOT** inside a `pre` tag

---

I know that I can just use the `:not` selector in plain [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```css
pre > code {
  color: red;
}

:not(pre) > code {
  color: blue;
}
```

But using it in [sass](/questions/tagged/sass) throws an error and fails to compile:

```
:not(pre) > code
  color: blue
```

Error:

```
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed



                     ^
      Invalid CSS after "...size: 1.5rem; }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "not(pre) : {"
      in /Users/Psy/my-app/src/styles/v3/base.sass (line 111, column 23)

File: src/styles/v3/base.sass

failed Re-building development bundle - 0.339s
```

---

**What is the correct way to do the same in Sass?**

To be clear: I'm not looking for other ways for "reorganizing" my Sass code. Instead, looking for an explicit selector where a tag is not inside another tag.

Comment: Looks OK to me: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/438b39e846c4f2946644fdcc59558863 are you terminating your line with a semi colon and the closing }

Comment: @lharby not the sass you showed, scss.

Comment: @lharby That's Scss, not Sass. I found we need to prefix it with `*`. Interesting to see it works for one but not the other.

Comment: The nature of the error message suggests that the issue might actually be at some point preceding the `:not()` line-- can you post a larger portion of this Sass file for context?

Comment: @AlexanderNied That's what confused me too but it points to a completely unrelated, valid sass code which works when the `:not` selector is removed. In any case, I figured out the problem (see answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I probably should've done this sooner, but [I searched Github](https://github.com/search?l=SASS&q=%3Anot(pre)&type=Code) to see how other [sass](/questions/tagged/sass) projects do the same.

Looks like while the `:not` selector works in SCSS the same way it works in CSS, we need to prefix the `:not` selector with `*` for SASS files:

```
*:not(pre) > code
  color: blue
```

This works without errors.

Comment: This is much more expensive than the method proposed by @dgknca

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but it's the most reasonable course of action at the moment where we're dealing with stylesheets from external libraries, specifically syntax highlighting ones that already use very explicit selectors.

Comment: Ah OK, that is unfortunate. I occasionally see * selectors in css and jquery and it always makes me wince.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `:not` selector. You can simply style the `code` and `code` under `pre` tag. This will provide the intended result:

```
code {
  color: blue;
}

pre > code {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: That was just an example. I'm looking for an explicit selector where a tag is not inside another tag.